# How to optimize the python code having nested lists with conditions in it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, performance, optimization

I would like to optimize the code atleast number of lines.
I am iterating over a list of urls and parsing the arguments in it , then iterations over a dictionary's keys if key found in url then i'm iterating through an list of words and list of arguments, if match found i am updating the dictionary. Really appreciate if any suggestions on this.

```
for url in urls:  # from List of urls 
args = dict(furl(url).args) # Fetch arguments passed in url as list
if args: # if there is any arguments were in  the list
    for j in dashboards1.keys(): # A list of keys dictionary  
        if re.findall(j,url): # Checking if the keys is present in url using regex
            for tm in tg_markets: # list of words
                for a in args: # list of arguments in the url 
                    if tm == a: # if match found .. 
                        dashboards1[j]['tg_count'] += 1 # updating the dictionary 
                        dashboards1[j][tm].append(furl(url).args[tm]) # updating the old dictionary
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, replace this:

```
for j in dashboards1.keys(): # A list of keys dictionary
```

by

```
for j,dashboard in dashboards1.items(): # A list of keys dictionary
```

Which allows to replace `dashboards1[j]` by `dashboard`: 2 key hashes suppressed.

Second, (and not least!!) this loop is useless:

```
        for a in args: # list of arguments in the url 
            if tm == a: # if match found .. 
                dashboards1[j]['tg_count'] += 1 # updating the dictionary 
                dashboards1[j][tm].append(furl(url).args[tm])
```

`args` is already a dictionary, so you're looping through the keys hoping to find `tm`. Just do:

```
        if tm in args: # list of arguments in the url 
            dashboard['tg_count'] += 1 # updating the dictionary 
            dashboard[tm].append(furl(url).args[tm]) # updating
```

(`dashboard` is `dashboards[j]` which has been optimized by my first suggestion)